# Опять по работе с ресурсами в Java

Tags: java, swing

Есть проект со структурой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть строка кода

```
icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/src/main/resources/FileTypesVideo.png"));
```

код находится в файле по пути /src/main/java/gui/file.java

как не изголялся, пробовал с начальным слэшем и без него, клал файл в разные папки, менял пути, изображение не цепляется, при запуске вываливается с NullPointerException

Comment: а трейс NPE можно получить? приложите к вопросу. пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("FileTypesVideo.png"));
```